# Filter data pulled from API to only read specific values

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, filter

I am pulling all customer information via an API and printing it in the console.

I am doing this with

```
 if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
 }
};
```

which gives all of the following data (changed for obvious reasons)

`{"id":2,"userIdent":"11","randomInfo":null,"isLead":false,"clientType":1,"companyName":null,"companyRegistrationNumber":null,"companyTaxId":null,"companyWebsite":null,"street1":"1234 Happy Rd","street2":null,"city":"Smile City","countryId":249,"stateId":22,"zipCode":"12345","fullAddress":"1234 Happy Rd, Smile City, MI","invoiceStreet1":null,"invoiceStreet2":null,"invoiceCity":null,"invoiceStateId":null,"invoiceCountryId":null,"invoiceZipCode":null,"invoiceAddressSameAsContact":true,"note":null,"sendInvoiceByPost":null,"invoiceMaturityDays":null,"stopServiceDue":null,"stopServiceDueDays":null,"organizationId":2,"tax1Id":null,"tax2Id":null,"tax3Id":null,"registrationDate":"2022-03-07T00:00:00-0500","leadConvertedAt":null,"companyContactFirstName":null,"companyContactLastName":null,"isActive":false,"firstName":"boop":[],"accountBalance":0.0,"accountCredit":0.0,"accountOutstanding":0.0,"currencyCode":"USD","organizationName":"My Company","bankAccounts":[],"tags":[],"invitationEmailSentDate":null,"avatarColor":"#ef6c00","addressGpsLat":11.22,"addressGpsLon":-22.11,"isArchived":false,"generateProformaInvoices":null,"usesProforma":false,"hasOverdueInvoice":false,"hasOutage":true,"hasSuspendedService":false,"hasServiceWithoutDevices":false,"referral":null}`

I only want to pull the value associated with, for example, "userIdent" which would be 11, but I'm not sure how to do this when I'm pulling the data from the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { userIdent } = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
console.log(userIdent) // "11"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var userIdent = data['userIdent'];
console.log(userIdent);
```

Comment: `var` in 2022...

Comment: Looks like this did exactly what I was asking for, thanks so much for your help!